# Business Intelligence Center Create

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, business-intelligence, business

I want to create Business Intelligence Center. I follow this steps:

> Configure a Business Intelligence Center
>
> When you create and configure a Business Intelligence Center, you create a new site collection and select the Business Intelligence Center site template. The Business Intelligence Center is a top-level site.
>
> To create a Business Intelligence Center
>
> -Verify that you have the correct administrative credentials. To create a site collection, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group on the computer that is running the SharePoint Central Administration website.
>
> -On the SharePoint Central Administration website home page, in the left navigation, click Application Management.
>
> -In Application Management, click Create site collections.
>
> -In the Title and Description section, in the Title box, type BI Center.
>
> -In the Web Site Address section, type BICenter in the box.
>
> -In most instances the complete URL for this site collection is http://your server name/sites/bicenter.
>
> -In the Template Selection section, click the Enterprise tab, and then click Business Intelligence Center.
>
> -In the Primary Site Collection Administrator section, type FarmAdmin.
>   Click OK.
>
> -When the top-level site (Business Intelligence Center) is successfully created, click OK.
>
> -Assign user permissions to the Business Intelligence Center.

I got the error. 
[image]

When I look the logs:

> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.12    w3wp.exe (0x07BC)                           0x0E04  Web Content Management          Publishing                      98e6    Monitorable The trial period for this product has expired.  8a49e89c-b3a9-404e-01bb-d6f62c62854e
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.12  w3wp.exe (0x07BC)                           0x0E04  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         75ov    Unexpected  Publishing Resources Feature activation failed. Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingResourcesFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties). 8a49e89c-b3a9-404e-01bb-d6f62c62854e
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.12  w3wp.exe (0x07BC)                           0x0E04  SharePoint Foundation           Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        Feature receiver assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', class 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingResourcesFeatureHandler', method 'FeatureActivated' for feature 'aebc918d-b20f-4a11-a1db-9ed84d79c87e' threw an exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingResourcesFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)   8a49e89c-b3a9-404e-01bb-d6f62c62854e
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.12  w3wp.exe (0x07BC)                           0x0E04  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72by    High        Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'PublishingResources' (ID: 'aebc918d-b20f-4a11-a1db-9ed84d79c87e').  Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingResourcesFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)  8a49e89c-b3a9-404e-01bb-d6f62c62854e
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.51  w3wp.exe (0x0E68)                           0x059C  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Task: SessionManager.PerformOngoingRequestDepartures   6b6b4445-3e47-0002-aa44-02ac06db33f7
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.77  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                       0x1690  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job MySite-Second-Instantiation-Interactive-Request-Queue). Parent No   a2d15b1a-fa84-4ba7-b05e-eb53bb76c301
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.77  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                       0x1690  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job MySite-Second-Instantiation-Interactive-Request-Queue    9249e89c-2374-404e-01bb-ddd52ec4d48d
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.77  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                       0x1690  SharePoint Portal Server        Personal Site Instantiation     aj58q   Medium       Starting timer My Site Second Instantiation Interactive Request Queue (28cae970-9721-4876-8dfb-e5c049c4a030) for web application: SharePoint - 80. Function: MySiteInstantiationJob:Execute   9249e89c-2374-404e-01bb-ddd52ec4d48d
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.77  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                       0x1690  SharePoint Portal Server        Personal Site Instantiation     aj58r   Medium       Finishing on timer My Site Second Instantiation Interactive Request Queue (28cae970-9721-4876-8dfb-e5c049c4a030) for web application: SharePoint - 80.  Function: MySiteInstantiationJob:Execute  9249e89c-2374-404e-01bb-ddd52ec4d48d
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:55.79  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                       0x1690  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job MySite-Second-Instantiation-Interactive-Request-Queue). Execution Time=18.2469   9249e89c-2374-404e-01bb-ddd52ec4d48d
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:56.01  w3wp.exe (0x0E68)                           0x1058  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Task: HealthPerfCounter    633d7a5d-300b-0002-b0ee-8e31d2e47a0f
>
> 02/10/2015 09:37:56.51  w3wp.exe (0x0E68)                           0x059C  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Task: SessionManager.PerformOngoingRequestDepartures   6b6b4445-3e47-0002-aa44-02ac06db33f7

Have you any information the issue?

Comment: It seems you do not have an enterprise license?

Comment: How can I get enterprise license?

Comment: That is something you normally sort with your license partner. You will ge a product key and then you need to activate enterprise features in your farm

Comment: How can i get product key and then activate enterprise features in my farm? Have you any advice site for processing? Robert Lindgren

Comment: As I said, you need to get the key from a licensing partner. Then you assign CALs to users (your partner should be able to give you the details). To activate enterprise features in Central Admin, do this : Go to SharePoint central administration -> Upgrade & migration -> Enable enterprise features. -> Choose the second option(enterprise) & Click OK.